# Google App Engine datastore 'distinct' not working in dev server or production

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Following code runs fine on production and dev server:

`outstanding_qs = models.SitePerformanceTrackingAnswers.all().run(projection=('questionnaire',))`

However, after adding the `distinct` parameter when calling `run` (as should be possible according to the documentation):

`outstanding_qs = models.SitePerformanceTrackingAnswers.all().run(projection=('questionnaire',), distinct=True)`

The following error is generated on both dev and production:

`TypeError: Unknown configuration option ('distinct')`

What am I doing wrong!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug. You can pass the query options to `.all()` though, to do the same thing. (And checking, this seems *not* to be documented... I'm fairly sure it works though)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ndb?  I see 'distinct' mentioned in the db class docs but not in ndb docs.